# Managing more 20,000 elements (search, pagination, etc...)

Tags: reactjs

I suppose my question is rather straight forward. I have a web app that has to deal with the pagination, search and organization of say - 20,000 elements. Imagine I had an inventory, and I want to be able to manage that in a dashboard.

I've seen React preload 3000 elements and handle it rather simply, but I've never seen a tutorial where that number is 5-6 times as great. Should I load the content in chucks, or is it okay to load it all in one go? How will React handle all of that data and perhaps - what would you do?

Before diving in, it would be nice to have a bit of direction here. :)

Comment: One thing I would recommend looking into virtualization, which is where you only render the items that are on screen (or just off screen, about to be scrolled to) - a good example of a library that could help you achieve this is the appropriately named [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized). How you would do it without a library, I couldn't tell you - thankfully none of my data has ever been that large :D

Comment: @JoeClay awesome, I'll look into that. Actually, my requirements are much larger than 20,000. I need to be able to handle 100,000+ items. So, that might be usual. Thank you for the info!

Comment: You should almost certainly not be loading 100,000+ items into your app in a single go. Just think of the network overhead. Only render what is on screen. The whole point of pagination is to not load massive data sets all at once.

Comment: Yeah, I'd second what @MatthewHerbst said - when you're working with data of that size, you'll always have to take into account things on both the client and the server. Virtualization is nice once you've actually loaded the data in to keep rendering snappy, but the actual requests to the server should be done in chunks as they're required too.

Comment: What if I want to do client side search or sorting/grouping? Would that ultimately have to be done server side or are their clever workarounds to keep things snappy?